# Can't open RDP redirected serial port

Tags: winapi, serial-port

I have a VM (Win10 x64) where my code runs, and my host is also Win10x64. I have an FTDI device connected to my host, and I need to use it with the guest. I have set up all (on both machines) to not prevent port redirecting. Port redirection seems to both work and not: it is not shown in the device manager albeit it looks to be there in all other places.

My code should be ok. It still fails on both `COM2`, `\\.\COM2`, and `\\\\.\\COM2`: it returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and puts 'The system cannot find the file specified' in GetLastError.

```
HANDLE m_hCommPort = CreateFile( port ,
                    GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                    NULL
                    );
```

(removing FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED makes no difference)

[image]

Even this works (I have no COM4, but I have COM2):

[image]

Is there an other syntax for redirected ports, or am I missing something?

Comment: Is your code running in the remote session, or is it a service / something similar?

Comment: This seems potentially relevant: https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/963#issuecomment-532729828  (Summary: The redirected ports aren't visible to the UAC elevated session)

Comment: @BenVoigt it is running in a remote session. Hmm... I will check that elevated session issue, as the IDE is running elevated.